# how to register COM+ application from VS Setup

Tags: .net, installation, com+

I'm trying to create an installer for my serviced component (queued component). Once the .NET DLL is installed on client machine, I want to register it as COM+ Application, as if by invoking `regsvcs MyAssembly.dll`. What is the best way to do it?

Can I invoke regsvcs from Windows Setup program, once it has installed my .NET DLL on client machine? In that case how do I refer appropriate regsvcs.exe available on client machine from my setup program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I've managed to do it by including regsvcs.exe as part of my installation package and writing a custom action to execute this exe. I consider it as a workaround and their might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom code to locate `regsvcs` on the client's machine. On my machine, it's `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegSvcs.exe`. I remember there's another version for v2.0 as well.